# C# input has to be 5 digits

Tags: c#

I have a question that asks the user to enter a student number, how can I make it so it will only accept a 5 digit number. The input is being added to an object like

```
console.writeline("Enter the student number: ");
```

then

```
studentObject.StudentNumber = int.Parse(Console.Readline());
```

I've tried using

```
if (Console.ReadLine().Length != 5)
{

  //Do this
}
else
{
   //Do this
}
```

But it won't work, the .Length says can't convert type int to bool. I'm stuck, any help please?

Comment: Which line gives the error? Your if statement looks fine to me. Post the code you have.

Comment: what is the type of studentnumber ? is it type of int or bool ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use *regular expressions*:

```
  String input;

  do {
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter student number:");
    input = Console.ReadLine();
  }
  while (!Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^\d{5}$")); // <- five digits expected

  // input contains 5 digit string
  int number = int.Parse(number);
```

P.S. In case that the input should be "five digit number, not *starting with zero*" the regular expression has to be changed to something like that:

```
 while (!Regex.IsMatch("12345", @"^[1-9]\d{4}$")); // five digits, not zero-starting
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer to your question, however one thing I noticed:

if you are using `Console.Readline()` in your if-statement  and then want to store it in the studentObject you will need to store it in a variable first. Calling `Console.Readline();` again to store it in the studentObject will cause another input to be expected, which nullifies your attempt to validate the input.

Something like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter student number:");

        //get the user input
        var number = Console.ReadLine();

        if (number.Length != 5)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Invalid format.");
        }
        else
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Yay it works");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var input = Console.ReadLine();
  int i;
 if (input.Length > 0 && input.Length < 6 && Int32.TryParse(input, out i))
                    // i has 5 digit;
                    else
                 // i has zero
```

Comment: I'm on mobile atm, sorry guys. My internet is down, so it's difficult to post all my code. StudentNumber is an int, it's set in a different class, field is private int _studentNumber and property is public int StudentNumber, get returns _studentNumber and I need an if statement (I think) inside the set, to check if what was entered is 5 digits, so when I ask for a 5 digit number the line that reads it is the studentObject.StudentNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Answer (score 0):

```
char[] cc = Console.Read().ToString().ToCharArray(); 
            if (char.IsDigit(cc[0])&&
                char.IsDigit(cc[1])&&
                char.IsDigit(cc[2])&&
                char.IsDigit(cc[3])&&
                char.IsDigit(cc[4]))
            {
                //Life's GOOD!
            }else { //bad input}
```

Note: I'm self-taught & don't have much knowledge. Correct me if wrong.